# "Correct" JSON format for array of information for eventual dropdown filling

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jsonparser

This is a little "cart before the horse" as I don't have an actual JSON source yet. (Still waiting on some access permissions.)

So in the meantime I have created a JSON that I believe will look like the data I am gathering. Ultimately I will have control of the php that generates it, so it could be something different if I am way off base.

My ultimate goal here is to parse this and use each tier to dynamically fill three dropdowns, but I haven't started writing the JavaScript for that yet.

My question is, is this JSON format "correct" or "appropriate" for wanting to dynamically fill three dropdowns in the following order:

(IE. I would gather and parse the JSON data on page load, and then only the first dropdown would be filled with possible groups. Then upon selecting the first dropdown, the second dropdown for FY would be populated with available FY data for that group, and then after selection, the third dropdown would be populated with the available quarter data for that specific group/FY. The dropdowns would be reactive, so that if the group was changed, the dropdowns would reset.)

HTML Dropdowns (Not generated dynamically yet):

```
<div class="form-group"><label>Choose Group</label>
                <select id="Portfolio" class="form-control">
                    <option value="value1">Group1</option>
                    <option value="value2">Group2</option>
                    <option value="value3">Group3</option>
                </select></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Choose FY</label>
                    <select id="FiscalYear" class="form-control">
                        <option value="value1">FY19</option>
                        <option value="value2">FY20</option>
                        <option value="value3">FY21</option>
                    </select></div>

                <label>Choose Quarter</label>
                <select id="Quarter" class="form-control">
                    <option value="value1">Q1</option>
                    <option value="value2">Q2</option>
                    <option value="value3">Q3</option>
                    <option value="value4">Q4</option>
                </select></div>
```

Proposed JSON Format:

```
{
    "FY19": [{
        "q1": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }],
        "q2": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }],
        "q3": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }],
        "q4": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }]
    }],
    "FY20": [{
        "q1": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }],
        "q2": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }],
        "q3": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }],
        "q4": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }]
    }],
    "FY21": [{
        "q1": [{
            "Group1": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group2": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }],
            "Group3": [{
                "Rate1": 91.4,
                "Rate2": 10.5,
                "Rate3": 97.5,
                "Rate4": 24,
                "Rate5": 97.5,
                "Rate6": 14.03,
                "Rate7": 74,
                "Rate8": 20,
                "Rate9": 69
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each Group you may want to make each key value pair an object.

```
{
"FY19": [
  {
    "q1": [
      {
        "group1": [
          {
            "Rate1": 90
          }]
       }]
   }],
 // "FY20": [... and so on]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will make accessing those values easier I believe? Now time to figure out how to fill the dropdowns!

Comment: I just looked over your json file again.  I realized you everything grouped the same way.  So let me extend my recommendation to all groupings of key:value pairs.  I'll edit my code above to reflect that.

Comment: If I have confused you!  Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)'s page on working with JSON.